# Wordpress: grabbing meta_value after save_post

Tags: php, wordpress, function

So I have been struggling with this for a while and can't get it to work.

I'm trying to send an email with meta_value inside it as soon as the post was first published, but nothing works.

I can get permalink and all other default Wordpress stuff to be sent, but can't get my meta_value to be sent. It shows blank. nothing.

Here's my code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'notifyauthor');
function notifyauthor($post_id) {
 
    $subject = 'my subject';
    $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $author_email = 'support@example.com';
    $meta =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'usp-custom-1', true);
    $message = 'my message body' . $meta . '' ;
       
   wp_mail($author_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

I have tried:

```
$meta =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'usp-custom-1', true);
```

also

```
$meta =  get_post_meta($post_id, 'usp-custom-1', true);
```

as well as

```
$meta =  usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-1');
```

All of the above get me a blank.

I have tried hook: `publish_post`. Same. didn't work.

I have read somewhere that `get_post_meta()` don't work with `save_post` when the post is newly created.

Help from any experienced coder would be appreciated.

Did anyone got that working somehow?

need help.

And yes, I did checked in a created post:

```
<?php $meta =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'usp-custom-1', true);
        echo $meta; ?>
```

It does work and output meta value successfuly.

Comment: If you change `$post->ID` to `$post_id` does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The `$post` variable that you're using is not available within your function scope.

The `save_post` action passes through the `ID` and `WP_Post` object which you can make use of. You currently have `$post_id` as a parameter of your function.

---

When using `add_action()` you can specify the number of arguments that should be provided to your function. Here is an example that makes `$post_id` and `$post` available to your function.

With this example, you will be able to use either `$post_id` or `$post->ID` in your code, as both are made available to you.

```php
function notifyauthor( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Your code here ...
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'notifyauthor', 10, 2 );
```

---

You find this action documented here: [wp-includes/post.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.7.2/wp-includes/post.php#L4384)